# Deleted the /use/bin/python3

Tags: rm, python3

I accidentally deleted the `/use/bin/python3`  by using rm `-rf /use/bin/python3`  and now it is showing bad interpreter: `no such file or directory`.

How do I restore it back ?

Comment: reinstall python?

Comment: It is giving me /use/bin/yum: /use/bin/python3: bad interpeter , no such file or directory , on trying to install anything

Comment: If you have python 2.x around somewhere, you may be able to set $PYTHONPATH to that version.  Otherwise, this might help:  [Installing Python 2.7 on centos without yum, gcc and no cd rom mounted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20127650/installing-python-2-7-on-centos-without-yum-gcc-and-no-cd-rom-mounted)

Comment: what device, os ... do you use?

Comment: I am using fedora 27 operating system